# How can I change the tipa font to Charter?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, font-encodings

I've tried `\usepackage{tipa}`, then `\DeclareFontSubstitution{T1}{bch}{m}{n}`, but nothing changes. Is there any way to make the tipa font be Charter, or another font that fits a little better?

Comment: Charis SIL, IIRC, has those characters. You need LuaTeX (or XeTeX) though.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As far as I know, IPA fonts for pdfLaTeX are available only in forms compatible with Computer Modern or Times.

Comment: I think one reason this doesn't work is that `tipa` doesn't use the `T1`encoding, but `T3`. So it won't have any effect when you substitute the `T1`font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Charis SIL in your computer (or any font that supports IPA characters), then you can use Xelatex or Lualatex. Here's an example with Xelatex.

Alternatively you can also use the `tipa` package with pdflatex, see also [the relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Linguistics#IPA_characters), but you would not be entering IPA directly, rather you'd use regular letters and Latex will interpret them.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}
\begin{document}
lɪŋˈgwɪstɪks
\end{document}
```